# This is (a) team work

Tags: idioms, indefinite-article, zero-article

1. This is team work.
2. This is a team work.

Which is correct?

You work or collaborate together with someone is the intended meaning.

Comment: It's usually written as the single word [teamwork](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/teamwork), which you can understand as a base noun ***work*** modified by ***team*** as a "noun adjunct". You wouldn't normally include the article ***a*** because it's really an [abstract noun](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abstract-noun) (like, say, ***fun***) if you're describing the *state* or the *activity*, rather than the job itself. If you're trying to describe *what you're doing*, it would be better to use a different base noun - *This is **a** team **effort, project, etc.***

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the quality of people working together as a team, then say *teamwork* - one word.  But you have to be talking about people and not an activity.

*Work* as a noun means "a productive activity" or "a result of a productive activity."  A person, however, is typically not considered a *work* (though his/her parents may disagree).

So you can qualify the noun *work* with the word *team* to mean something like "a productive activity for the team" or "the result of a productive activity by the team", but this does not really translate to "a quality of people working together as a team."

Idiomatically, no one says "This is a team work" because of possibility of confusion with *teamwork.*  You can say the more common string of words "This is a team *effort*" to mean that an effort should not be done by one person.

Answer (score 0):

**This is team work.** (For nouns)

Without including "a" it's similar to say

*"This is stackexchange.com"* or 
*"This is E entertainment television"*

It's correct if we're trying to say that ***this what we do represents the truly team work (noun)***

**This is a team work.** (for the action of do things together)

Including "a" it's correct if we mean that ***We do this together, this(action) is a team work, you know why? because we're a team, teams do team work (noun).***

I hope it helps!

Comment: what is a noum?

Answer (score 0):

1, This is team work, is most correct, but would only be used in very specific cases.

> Great job guys in setting up the reception hall, *this* is team work! (While pointing to the work just done.)

The noun form of this expression is most often "Team Effort".

> We've got an hour to set up the reception hall, let's make this a team effort.